# PhpStorm doesn't detect undefined variables at all

Tags: variables, phpstorm, undefined-behavior

PhpStorm will not detect undefined variables in my PHP code. No idea, why! As I remember, not defined variables have been detected in past, but not any more. Any ideas why?

Here is my configuration setting:

[image]

`$sendFolders` is not defined anywhere, but PhpStorm will not detect this :=(

[image]

Comment: 1) If you create a brand new empty project and put this file there -- will it work OK there? It's hard to say much from this **small** fragment -- maybe you do have it defined elsewhere... 2) If you `Ctrl+Click` on it -- will it take you anywhere? 3) If still nothing -- please do `File | Invalidate Caches..." and restart the IDE -- any better? 40 Is still nothing -- disable all custom (not bundled by default) plugins and restart the IDE. Still no changes?